# Repeated zero eigenvalues 3x3 and higher

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix

$$A= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
      2 & 2 & -2 \\ 
      5 & 1 & -3 \\ 
      1 & 5 & -3
   \end{pmatrix}
$$

I want to find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors. I've tried this question multiple times but I end up with the same answer which is $\lambda^3 = 0$.

Q1) Can I have 3 repeated eigenvalues and can they all be zero?

Q2) Is my working out correct? Do you end up with $\lambda^3 = 0$?

Q3) If indeed we can have 3 repeated eigenvalues at zero, how do I find the eigenvectors?

Thank you

Comment: Q1 is of course possible I guess

Comment: This matrix is not diagonalizable. There is only one eigenvalue, namely  $\lambda=0$. The dimension  of $V_0$ is $1$. Thus there is only one eigenvector (up to linear independence) corresponding to $\lambda=0$. You can find the eigenvector by calculating $\ker(A-\lambda Id)$.

Comment: You find eigenvectors the same way regardless of multiplicity. You might not get three linearly independent vectors for this matrix, though.

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda^3 = 0$ is indeed characteristic equation.

You have only one true eiegnvector.

$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$

You have 2 "generalized eigenvectors.

Find $v_2$ such that

$Av_2 = \lambda v_2 + v_1$

In which case:

$(A-\lambda I)v_2 = v_1\\
(A-\lambda I)^2v_2 = (A-\lambda I)v_1 = 0$

And since $\lambda = 0$

$A^2 v_2 = 0$

$A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}12&-4&-4\\12&-4&-4\\24&-8&-8\end{bmatrix}$

And $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ would be a candidate.

Except $Av_2 = 4v_1$

now you need $v_3$ such that $Av_3 = v_2$

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&\frac {1}{16}\\1&\frac 14 &-\frac 1{16}\\2&-\frac 14&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac 14&\frac14&\frac 14\\2&2&-2\\12&-4&-4\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the last line. I can see the first matrix is the eigenvectors, I'm guessing the one on the right is the inverse. What is the one in the middle?

Comment: Also how did you get $A^2v_{2}$=0?

Comment: $Av_2 = v_1$, and $Av_1 = 0$ so $A^2v_2 = 0$  The last line, this matrix does not daigonalize, but it can be put into "Jordan normal" form which is what I have done.